# _str__ returned non-string (type JpegImageFile) While trying to use image as button in tkinter python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

_str__ returned non-string (type JpegImageFile) while trying to use image as button in Tkinter. I tried file= instead of Image.open but that didn't work too. Can someone tell me how to fix this

Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Window setup

mainwindow = Tk()
mainwindow.geometry('420x420')
mainwindow.title('Root Screen')

# Button image source

temp_img = PhotoImage(Image.open('D:\\Coding\\Python_stuff\\Watch_T800\\temp_img.jpg'))
temp_img_lbl = Label(image=temp_img)
temp_img_lbl.pack()

# Button function 

def menufun():
    menuwindow = Tk()
    menuwindow.geometry('420x420')
    menuwindow.title('Menu')
    
    temp = Button(menuwindow, text="Temperature",height=5, width=10, image=temp_img)
    temp.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Home Buttons

menu = Button(mainwindow, text="Menu", command=menufun).pack()

# BG Image

bg=Image.open('D:\\Coding\\Python_stuff\\Watch_T800\\background.png')
blah1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg)
lbl=Label(mainwindow, image=blah1)
lbl.pack()

mainloop()
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Python_stuff\Watch_T800\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    temp_img_lbl = Label(image=temp_img)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yashw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3204, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\yashw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2628, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type JpegImageFile)
```

I already explained what I tried in the , But I'm telling it again

I have tried using file= instead of image.open but it says

Pyimage1 Not found

Comment: `temp_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage` (note the "ImageTk" part that you forgot)

Comment: Do not use Image.open. Give the pathname to the PhotoImage constructor

Comment: The "Pyimage1" error is because you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, the second and subsequent windows should be instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score -1):

Add lower letter r.

Change this :

```
temp_img = PhotoImage(Image.open('D:
```

to:

```
temp_img = PhotoImage(Image.open(r'D:
```

Als0 this too:

```
bg=Image.open(r'D:
```